# Jenkins - How to find out which tests failed repeatedly?

Tags: jenkins

I am new to CI & Jenkins. I have a Java project which runs Testng based automated tests. The tests run regularly as a job in Jenkins. Sometimes, the job fails repeatedly for a long time. But, in each run, the number of test failures is different. I want to see which tests failed repeatedly in, say the last 5 runs. With that, I can reduce the number of test failures which I have to investigate. The failures which do not repeat all in the last 5 runs could be ignored or investigated later.

Can someone please suggest how I can find out which tests failed repeatedly in some consecutive runs ?

**PS** - Here is an example to explain why I want to see test failures in the past few runs.

```
Run 1 - test1 failed, test3 failed, test10 failed.
Run 2 - test3 failed, test17 failed.
Run 3 - test1 failed, test3 failed.
```

After looking at these 3 runs, we see that test3 fails in all the runs. But, the other tests pass in at least one of the three runs. I know that test3 used to pass before I started these 3 runs. This tells me that test3 might be failing due to a bug in the system, but the other tests might be failing due to intermittent issues in the system. This info allows me to decide which test to investigate first, i.e. test3. I can look at the other tests later if needed.

Comment: somehow you need to save the test-results preferable in an easy kind to see the fails. Could be just in the form 'XEXX' where E stands for error and the whole line for all tests. Like that you could save it in a textfile without much space.

Comment: for each run of all  tests you make a new line, then it's easy to see or to analyze by script.

Comment: You have the test-ng plugin available and you can publish the results each time... then you can compare each build which will tell you which test failed

Comment: @rohitthomas - Are you suggesting to manually compare builds ? I want to avoid that.

Comment: What do you consider 'failed repeatedly'? Do you mean all testcases tha failed in the last 5 runs for example or only every testcase that failed in 3 out of 5 executions?

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell - All the tests which failed in the last 5 runs. I'll update the question to explain why I am asking for this.

Answer (score 9):

You can take the number of times a test failed from the build's object in a pipeline: you can make a small report and attach it to your build like so:

```groovy
@NonCPS
def getRepeatedlyFailingTests(int timesFailedAtLeast = 2) {
  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class)
    .getFailedTests()
    // Keep only tests that failed at least twice
    .findAll { it.age >= timesFailedAtLeast }
    .collect { [ "${it.className}.${it.name}".trim(), it.age ] }
}

def saveRepeatedlyFailingTestsReport() {
  def header = [ "test", "times-failed" ]
  def records = getRepeatedlyFailingTests()
  def report = "repeatedly-failing-tests.csv"
  writeCSV file: report, records: [ header ] + records, format: CSVFormat.EXCEL
  archiveArtifacts report
}
```

Call `saveRepeatedlyFailingTestsReport` after you gather your test results and you'll see the report in your latest build artifacts link.

Comment: Which language is this ? Could you please add more details ? I'll add a bounty to hopefully make it worthwhile. thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev this is the Groovy DSL that's used within Jenkins pipeline. If you only need visual aid I would go with Sooraj's answer, since it doesn't require pipeline knowledge. To build a complete pipeline I'll need to know your freestyle job, but that's out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Test Result Analyzer plugin from Jenkins to analyse the trends of tests.

[Test Result Analyzer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin)

[Video Tutorial from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FWtDEAr1Kw)

**Installation**:

1. In Jenkins Dashboard, click on ***Manage Jenkins***
2. From the menu select ***Manage Plugins***
3. Click on ***Available*** tab and input ***analyzer*** in the Filter search box
4. Click the check box to the left of ***Test Results Analyzer*** and click the ***Install without restart*** button

**Usage**:

1. Go to the project and click on ***Configure***
2. Goto Post-build Actions section and select ***Publish JUnit test result report***
   from the Add post-build action dropdown
3. In the Test report XMLs field provide the path of the TestNg/JUnit xml in the project. For example - `**/target/test-results/*.xml` in my case
4. Save the configuration
5. Then after a successful build, goto your project, and click on the ***Test Results Analyzer*** on the left side menu

Comment: Thanks for the link. But, Link only answers don't help much. Could you please add a brief description of how I could use the plugin to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Install the plugin and configure the plugin to the desired project's _Post-build Actions_.
Then after a successful build you can see the results by clicking on the _Test Result Analyzer_ on the left side menu of your project

Comment: @Borat Sagdiyev, I have updated the answer with detailed steps and a video to configure the **Test Results Analyser** plugin. Hope this helps ;)